# Visual Designer for JSF

Tags: jsf, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for JSF development and...is there any Visual Web Designer plugin for JSF in Netbeans 6.9.1?

I am a sloppy guy, so without a visual aid for web development, I pretty much messed up my web UI.

Comment: @Sugandha that thread doesnt state if there is any visual editor for JSF on netbeans. I meant something like visual studio design view.

Comment: This maybe a bit late since the last time you asked this question, but are you still looking for a Visual JSF  tool. My team is actually working on one and will be releasing the first version soon. Would you like to take a look at it?

Comment: @Jas I no longer develop in Java but sure :). Can you give me the link?

Comment: Is it possible to get your email so that I can contact you when the first release is ready? If you would rather not share e-mail over Internet, my contact info is listed on my profile. Or if you would rather not share e-mail at all, I can come back and post here when we're ready. Just let me know your preferences :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit late but it might help. Under Netbeans 7.0 you can install Visual Web as a plugin  in the plugin manager from this catalog

[catalog](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/7.0/uc/m2/dev/catalog.xml)

Hope it helps

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Visual aid is no more available since `Netbeans 6.9` release.

You can find those in previous netbeans version. I have seen it in 6.7, where you install JSF pluggin and can find an option to create `Visual JSF page`

Check following links for more info

1. [Link 1](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Visual-Java-Server-Faces-td2953632.html)
2. [Link 2](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/plug-in-for-visual-web-jsp-designer-drag-amp-drop-td3274182.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are so many jsf component libraries which is one of the reasons that there will never be a decent designer. All there is content assist available in all major IDEs and IMHO that is all you need. Generated code from designers isnt worth much most of the time anyway.

1. There is Rich faces plugin from JBoss in Eclipse
2. There is OEOPE from Oracle where is JSF designer for Eclipse
3. Netbeans doesnt have any now
4. IntelliJ Idea doesnt have WYSIWYG either as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

To find what `Netbeans` recommends, go to 
http://wiki.netbeans.org/VisualWebSupport

Comment: the problem with Netbeans is, eventhough it is directly under Sun (hence now under Oracle) is its incapability to be the all-in-one solution for Java needs, unlike Eclipse. Too bad I hate eclipse, its cumbersome, plugins hell etc. I just wish that Netbeans will have the visual editor so that I can totally discard Eclipse.