# Visual JSF Designer

Tags: jsf, designer

Please can any one tell me from where I can have Visual JSF designer that can be integrated with Eclipse ? 
And Why netbeas doesn't have this functionality

I know that Myeclipse provides this ability, but it;s just run on 32-bit in addition it's not free. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210592/visual-designer-for-jsf

Comment: @berkay, he is asking for a visual designer for **Eclipse**, while your link has the **NetBeans** and **JDeveloper** related ones.

Comment: Warning: drag'n'dropping code without actually understanding the generated code will end up in disaster.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the **Dynamic Web Module** facet and **JavaServer Faces facet** added on your project, right click on the page you want and choose *Open with -> Web Page Editor*.

[image]

That works only with pure JSF tags, not with third party library ones like Primefaces. You can also go through [JSF Web Page Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971629/jsf-eclipse-designer), but not sure how it will work since it looks it's not updated since long time ago.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am totally new on JSF . I don't know how to do that is there any link to show this in steps
I don't know if I have Dynamic web module ? or JSF facet
thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Right click on the project -> properties and search for **Project Facets**.

Comment: It would be better to [install JBoss Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/420896#.UQkdo-lQC0w), this still doesn't provide support for PrimeFaces tag components but it renders the JSF and RichFaces tag components.